# "up to" vs "over"

Tags: sentence-construction

> I climbed over the roof

vs.

> I climbed up to the roof.

(At first I was on the ground and now I am on the roof of the room – actually, I climbed up a ladder to the roof. But how can I make a sentence ommiting the word "ladder"?)

Also:

> The cat climbed up the hedge of the wall

vs:

> The cat climbed over the hedge of the wall.

(The cat at first was on the ground and now it is sitting on the hedge of the wall of the yard.)

Answer (score 1):

In American English we would say you climbed up to the roof. If you said you climbed over the roof then you were on the roof but aren't now.  One other point, rooms have ceilings. Houses have roofs. The roof is the exterior top of a building and the ceiling is the interior top of a room.

Cheers!

Comment: I'd say "you climbed onto the roof", is it OK?

Comment: Yes, that's fine, in fact I would prefer it if the result was that you were on the roof.  Climbing up to the roof could also mean getting as far as the roof without actually getting onto it.

Answer (score 1):

If you were fixing the roof you'd climb onto it, if you only were interested in the guttering, you'd climb up to it.

Only if your intent was to arrive on the other side of the house would you climb over it.

This all presumes that you are, in fact, outdoors; not, as Maurice points out, indoors & climbing up to the ceiling - which, unless you were Lionel Richie, is where you would stop.

[image]